# Debugger crashing in vs 2012 with IIS 7.5

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I had a web project setup to run through IIS and now all of a sudden the debugger does not work. It crashes and restarts vs 2012 each time I try and run it. I can run the debugger using the built in server and I can run it on new projects I setup and hook up to IIS.

It seems like some how this one went flaky on me and I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.60315.1, time stamp: 0x5142bb7b
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b83c8a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
Faulting process id: 0x1178
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce81aaa9ffdace
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: c2498861-ed9e-11e2-ba62-10604b7df519

Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   at Microsoft.VsPixPkg.XXX_DebugLaunchHook.OnLaunchDebugTargets(UInt32, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsDebugTargetInfo4[], Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsDebugTargetProcessInfo[])
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsDebugger3.LaunchDebugTargets3(UInt32, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsDebugTargetInfo3[], Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsDebugTargetProcessInfo[])
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.DebugCfg.DebugLaunch(UInt32)

Comment: I am having the **exact** same problem starting around the same time. What virus scanner are you using? I am researching if McAfee Enterprise 8.8 is getting in the way of the cross bit-depth remote debugging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to debug through IIS when I had the multiple worker processes setup. Once I set it back to one, everything worked fine.